# Automatically reply to an email

Tags: java, email, exchange-server

I'm working on a project I'm Java with regards to outlook.

Here I'm able to do all the functions like Read a mail, write a mail, reply to a mail etc...

But now we've been thinking of taking it to the next level.

Our plan is as below.

We have an email address like `info@myDomain.com`, when ever an email is sent to this address, I need to reply them. Here basically customers send an email asking for some data, and we've the data available in our portal, and we just need to send it. 
The response would be Like `thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon. Mean while please look into this {URL}`.

And this has to be done automatically when ever there is an email hit to this particular email address.

Couple of questions:
- should my machine be on the whole day to get this thing done. 
- is  there a way that a Java application can automatically monitor my inbox to see for this case match. 
- Also, can I have this running in the bg.

Can someone please point me into the right direction/approach where can I can start working on this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> when ever an email is sent to this address, I need to reply them.

1. For this you need to monitor your email account fro incoming emails. [Here](http://www.developer.com/java/data/monitoring-email-accounts-imap-in-java.html) is one of the way to do this

> The response would be Like thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you soon. Mean while please look into this {URL}.

2. Once you receive an email (using above email monitoring approach), you need to call a method that sends the reply with above format

> And this has to be done automatically when ever there is an email hit to this particular email address.

3. Above two steps accomplishes this task.

> should my machine be on the whole day to get this thing done

Basically, you will need an application server (like tomcat) where your above java program is deployed. So, yes this server needs to be running and available all the time.

> is there a way that a Java application can automatically monitor my inbox to see for this case match

Check point 1

> Also, can I have this running in the bg
>   You can run tomcat as a service in windows ([more info](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-service)). It has many advantages, automatic startup on boot being the one. Similar implementations are also available for other OS.

So, in short, this can be accomplished. It is bit complex but not much difficult. Cheers